# Fraction within another fraction

Tags: fractions

Im using the code as shown below to write a step by step for a question but when i have a fraction in another fraction it becomes small and hard to read. i wish to make the faction inside the same size as the other and clear but not too crowded.

```
\begin{align*}
    \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
    \\
    \tan(a+b)&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
    \\
    &=\frac{\frac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} + \frac{\cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}{\frac{\cos a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} - \frac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
    \\
    &=\frac{\frac{\sin a}{\cos a} + \frac{\sin b}{\cos b}}{1 - \frac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
    \\
    &=\frac{\tan a +\tan b }{1 - \tan a \tan b}
\end{align*}
```

[image]

Comment: Add `\displaystyle` before the small fraction, or (with `amsmath`), use `\dfrac`.

Comment: when i do that there ends up having a really small gap between the small fraction bottom and big fractions line and other small fraction top

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `\cfrac` for nested fractions. However this makes the ‘upper’ denominators too close from the main fraction line, so one can compensate adding a phantom letter with descenders. No compensation required for the ‘lower’ numerators if you use `\cfrac` (not `\dfrac`).

Another possibility would use the `\mfrac`(medium-sized fraction – 80 % of \displaystyle) command from `nccmath`, so the smaller fractions are still readable. Here is an example of both methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath, nccmath}

\begin{document}

    \begin{align*}
        \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
        \\
        \tan(a+b)&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\cfrac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} + \cfrac{\cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b\vphantom{g}}}{\cfrac{\cos a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} - \cfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\cfrac{\sin a}{\cos a} + \cfrac{\sin b}{\cos b \vphantom{g}}}{1 - \cfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\tan a +\tan b }{1 - \tan a \tan b}
    \end{align*}\medskip

    \begin{align*}
        \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
        \\
        \tan(a+b)&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\mfrac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} + \mfrac{\cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b\vphantom{g}}}{\mfrac{\cos a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} - \mfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\mfrac{\sin a}{\cos a} + \mfrac{\sin b}{\cos b\vphantom{g}}}{1 - \mfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
        \\[0.5ex]
        &=\frac{\tan a +\tan b }{1 - \tan a \tan b}
    \end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

To remedy the small (`\textstyle`) equations, as I said in a comment, add `\displaystyle` before the small fraction, or (with `amsmath`), use `\dfrac`.   However, that does not address the narrow vertical gap between really tall equations.

With a TABstack, the gap between equations can be easily specified.  Here, because the equation(s) is/are unnumbered, and the height of each equation is different, I choose a `\alignShortstack` instead of an `\alignCenterstack`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,tabstackengine}
\TABstackMath
\TABstackMathstyle{\displaystyle}
\begin{document}
\[
\setstackgap{S}{16pt}
\alignShortstack{
    \frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
    \\
    \tan(a+b)&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}
    \\
    &=\frac{\dfrac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} + \dfrac{\cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}{\dfrac{\cos a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} - \dfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
    \\
    &=\frac{\dfrac{\sin a}{\cos a} + \dfrac{\sin b}{\cos b}}{1 - \dfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
    \\
    &=\frac{\tan a +\tan b }{1 - \tan a \tan b}}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

with use of `amsmath` and manuals increased vertical distance between math equation's lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
\frac{\sin(a+b)}{\cos(a+b)}
&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}               \\
\tan(a+b)
&=\frac{\sin a \cos b + \cos a \sin b\mathstrut}{\cos a \cos b - \sin a \sin b}      \\[1ex]
&=\frac{\dfrac{\sin a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b\mathstrut} + \dfrac{\cos a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}
       {\dfrac{\cos a \cos b}{\cos a \cos b} - \dfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}\\[1ex]
&=\frac{\dfrac{\sin a}{\cos a} + \dfrac{\sin b\mathstrut}{\cos b}}
       {1 - \dfrac{\sin a \sin b}{\cos a \cos b}}                                   \\[1ex]
    &=\frac{\tan a +\tan b }{1 - \tan a \tan b}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**edit:** now is considered comment of Barbara Beeton.

Comment: The fractions in the numerator appear too close to the fraction line compared to what's below the fraction line.  This might be improved by adding `\mathstrut` to each of the denominators in the numerator fractions.  (But it will probably never look wonderful.)

Comment: @Zarko: I'm sorry, Iinadvertently posted an image of my resulting pdf with your answer instead of my answer. Can you undo what I did?

Comment: i will add edit my answer with my edit ...

Comment: @barbarabeeton, thank you very much. i consider your suggestion in my answer.